# Inner logic of chained redirections

Tags: shell, io-redirection

When I type

```
cat some_file > new_file1 > new_file2
```

I got output from `some_file` in `new_file2` and empty `new_file1`.

What is the inner logic in it? More specifically what is the `stdout` of file?

Note: On Windows the middle file is skipped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the shell.

In bash, `echo derp >file1 >file2` first opens `file1`, truncates it, then arranges for the `stdout` of `echo derp` to be written to `file1`. Then bash does the same for `file2`: it opens `file2`, truncates it, and arranges for the `stdout` of `echo derp` to be written instead to `file2`.

The net effect is that `file1` is truncated (i.e. the content is deleted) and `stdout` only goes into `file2`. There is no chaining taking place. Bash is only capable of redirecting stdout to one place at a time. This is true for pipes as well: `echo derp > file | cat` results in "derp" be written to the file, not to the pipe.

In zsh, however, `echo derp >file1 >file2` writes to both `file1` and `file2`, as you might intuitively expect. See MULTIOS in `man zshmisc` for details if you use zsh.

To achieve this outside of `zsh`, you can simply use `tee`: `echo derp | tee file1 file2 > /dev/null` is equivalent to zsh's `echo derp >file1 >file2`.

Comment: +1 for teaching me `tee` can write to multiple files at once. For at least the bash part, `file1` and `file2` are created if they don't exist yet.